# Deprecate a type in ApolloServer

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

This is the pattern to deprecate a field in ApolloServer:

```
type Car {
  id: ID!
  make: String
  model: String
  description: String @deprecated(reason: "Field is deprecated!")
}
```

However, how do I deprecate a whole type - e.g. the `Car` type above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Types cannot be deprecated. Only fields and enum values may be deprecated. This is shown in the definition of the `@deprecated` directive [here](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec--deprecated):

```
directive @deprecated(
  reason: String = "No longer supported"
) on FIELD_DEFINITION | ENUM_VALUE
```

and explained [here](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Deprecation) (emphasis mine):

> To support the management of backwards compatibility, GraphQL **fields and enum values** can indicate whether or not they are deprecated (`isDeprecated: Boolean`) and a description of why it is deprecated (`deprecationReason: String`).

Deprecation is meant to indicate to the client to stop requesting the deprecated elements. Since a client doesn't request a specific type, only specific fields, deprecating a type doesn't really make sense.

Comment: As an aside, I could see type deprecation in the context of fragment usage, but regardless it's just not part of the current spec.